# Issues switching activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio, and am creating an app for an event. I have the homepage, with ImageButton's that will open a new activity - Event Information, containing text and a button. The application has a bottom navigation, and once the Event Information has been opened, everytime I click a button on the bottom navigation, it opens the required activity, but the button from the Event Location is on top of the new activity. I can't click on anything on the required activity, just the button that seems to remain on top of all the activities. I am not receiving any errors fro this and have no idea on how to fix it.

Here is the java code for the Event Information page:

```
public class EventInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button eventLocationButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_information);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationListener);

        eventLocationButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_EventLocation);

        eventLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent openEventInformation = new Intent(EventInformation.this, Location.class);
                startActivity(openEventInformation);
            }
        });
    }

public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationListener);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_contactInformation:
                            selectedFragment = new ContactFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_location:
                            selectedFragment = new LocationFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

The EventInformation layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.u1854455.kimmisquickbook.EventInformation">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Event Inofmation"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/backgroundBlue"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/backgroundBlue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="The event you have chosen is: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/message"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_Artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Name: Drake"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Date: 5th October 2019"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lb_Artist"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_Time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Start tiime: 19:30"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lb_Date"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_City"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End time: Late"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_Location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Location: First Direct Arena, Leeds"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lb_City"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="87dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_EventLocation"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="Event Location"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/lb_Location"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="372dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The location layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add layout files for both EventInformation and Location activities to the question description. Most likely your second activity is not full-screen, or it may contain the same button and cause confusion. The layout files will help to understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, what is a layout file?

Comment: In your case, this is `activity_event_information.xml` that you have in your project.

Comment: @ReazMurshed thank you, I have now added them in

Comment: I have just noticed that switching between activities using the bottom navigation view also stops buttons on the homepage working once I go back to that page, not too sure if the issue lies with the bottom navigation view?